# Alternatives to Brute Force Search (Language Unspecific)

Tags: brute-force

I am using a brute force method to optimize a solution in one of my recent projects and it is working quite well.  **Basically the optimization process involves searching for a global maximum in the space of all possible solutions.**  I was curious if there are other techniques which can be used to speed up a brute force search or other methods entirely.  This is an area that I have little experience in but, as I said, I am quite curious.

Comment: I think you might need to expand on the database, language, and what you're searching for.

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? It would be helpful if we knew more information about your problem.

Comment: This is very general but I am essentially finding a global maximum in the space of all possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Genetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) are a good way to find maximums, even when is not possible to test all solutions.

It's a wide spread technique and there are implementations in very programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

[Simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) is useful for solving local maxima problems, but is not always guaranteed to find the global maxima. It basically uses random 'jumps' in an attempt to find a better location/value than its current, and this can speed up searches.